# Check if app not install suggested download it when user navigate to my website from android browser?

Tags: android, android-browser, android-install-apk

I've googled more about linking to app via browser, but I can not found my solution.
I used from this manifest code:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/apk" android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/apk" android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

but when I navigation to http://example.com/apk, I don't see any `complete action using` dialog. But when I entered http://example.com/apk in [google search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) app everything is OK.
So I want when user navigate to my application homepage from android device browser, if my app was not install on user device, suggested it to install else navigated user to my app homepage.
In other hand I want introduce my other app in my homepage, and I want when clicked that, another `complete action using` dialog appear for select open it with my app.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What browser are you using? Not every browser handle such app linking.

Comment: @SimonMarquis I used from my devices default browser. My devices are Sony-Arc-S and Samsung galaxy note.

Comment: Try with Chrome to see if it's working.

Comment: @SimonMarquis In Samsung device I test it both default browser which have name 'internet' and with Chrome

Comment: And it's not working I suppose? Maybe you already set the default action once... Try to delete the default action of your network browsers in the settings app.

Comment: @SimonMarquis `no defaults set.` for browser.